# when i select debug app option in Android Studio this error comes: Error running 'app': Error retrieving capabilities from the device 127.0.0.1:62001

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, nox

When I select the debug app option in Android Studio, this error comes:
Error running 'app': Error retrieving capabilities from the device 127.0.0.1:62001

[image]

Has anyone encountered such a case so far?

Comment: Yes, this error started after I updated to Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 1 and logcat stopped working completely, I've tried everything to solve it, without success

Comment: I just clean , restart AS and works..

Comment: damned be the day I decided to upgrade to Giraffe...

Comment: Also happening to me. Cleaning, clearing cache, or restarting haven't worked.

Comment: Try with another testing device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with nox-Player.
The problem was solved by installing Android Studio's own emulator.

Comment: Android Studio's own emulator also doesn't work., which version is Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Just try to run the app in a different testing device.